# How to add support for category excerpts?

Tags: add-theme-support, post-type-support

How do I add support for excerpts for post categories in the admin?  I have tried the following, but to no avail:

```
add_post_type_support('category', 'excerpt');
add_post_type_support('post_category', 'excerpt');
add_post_type_support('taxonomy', 'excerpt');
```

It's got to be something like this, but I just don't know.

Comment: Categories usually don't have excerpts but they support descriptions by default. Are you looking to create an excerpt from the category description or do you not have a category description when editing a term?

Comment: I need a piece of information that I can use to represent the category on other pages.  Like a shortened version of a category description.  If there is no built-in way to do this, then I will use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, but intuition says there is probably a way without it.

Comment: There isn’t. You’ll need to make your own.

Comment: As others said, you can "fake" an excerpt, but I think you should ake a look at ACF, you can add any type of field into your category !